# Why can't for_each modify its functor argument?

Tags: c++, stl, foreach

> http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/for_each/ 
>   Unary function taking an element in
>   the range as argument. This can either
>   be a pointer to a function or an
>   object whose class overloads
>   operator(). Its return value, if any,
>   is ignored.

According to this article, I expected that for_each actually modifies the object given as its third argument, but it seems like for_each operates on a temporary object, and doesn't even modify the object given to it.

So, why is it implemented in that way? It seems much less useful. Or did I misunderstand something and my code below contains errors?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

template <class T> struct Multiplicator{
    T mresult;
  public:
    const T& result() const{return mresult;}
    Multiplicator(T init_result = 1){
      mresult = init_result;
    }
    void operator()(T element){
      mresult *= element;
      std::cout << element << " "; // debug print
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> vec;
    vec.push_back(1);
    vec.push_back(2);
    vec.push_back(3);
    Multiplicator<double> multiply;
    std::for_each(vec.begin(),vec.end(),multiply);
    std::cout << "\nResult: " << multiply.result() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Expected output:

```
1 2 3 Result: 6
```

But got following output:

```
1 2 3 Result: 1
```

Comment: How about changing your question title? Might make it easier for others to find.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The function object is taken by value.  `for_each` returns the function object, so if you change it to:

```
multiply = std::for_each(vec.begin(),vec.end(),multiply);
```

you get the expected output.

Comment: Generally for functors, and because they are supposed to be lightweight and copyable, I cheat and use an attribute that references a variable passed into the constructor. Thus any copy is stricly equivalent and refers to the same item. Of course, it makes initialization a bit awkward (declare variable, pass it to functor, read from variable), but it works fine and does not require any particular implementation propriety (like not discarding the just modified functor).

Comment: Lemme give you the first gold STL badge

Comment: @Johannes:  Thank you, but I have to answer another 36 questions tagged [stl] first :-) (the requirement is now at least 1,000 upvotes and at least 200 answers; I remember when they changed it a year ago and I lost my gold [c] badge for a couple months.)

Answer (score 10):

While James is correct, using [`std::accumulate`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/numeric/accumulate/) with [`std::multiplies`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/functional/multiplies/) would be more correct, probably:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

int main(void)
{
    std::vector<double> vec;
    vec.push_back(1);
    vec.push_back(2);
    vec.push_back(3);

    double result = std::accumulate(vec.begin(), vec.end(),
                                    1.0, std::multiplies<double>());

    std::cout << "\nResult: " << result << std::endl;

}
```

With your `for_each` version, you don't really need to copy the functor again, rather:

```
double result = std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), multiply).result();
```

Or C++0x, for fun:

```
double result = 1;
std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [&](double pX){ result *= pX; });
```

Comment: What is this, "suggest the right tool for the job day?"  :-)  +1

Comment: @James: 8​​​​​​) Unfortunately, the quality of my answers decreases exponentially as the day continues. :p

Answer (score 0):

The semantics of For_each dont fit into what you are trying to do. accumulate does exactly what you are trying, use that instead.